# Second float of Unity Blend tree is always NaN

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity is on 2022.3.13f1

[image: The Blend Tree displaying Y as NaN]

X and Y are two float parameters in an animator, Blend Tree is set to 2D simple directional, and Blend Tree is saying Y is NaN.

Switching the position of X & Y just makes X NaN.

[image: X as NaN]

Making both X or both Y makes them normal

[image: Y in both parameter slots, being normal]

Tried restarting Unity, didn't work.
Tried resetting Blend Tree, didn't work.
Tried finding NaN in .controller file, couldn't find any.
Clicking on it does nothing.

(I just used 2 blend trees to do the same feature, but it still says NaN when in 2D blend type)

Comment: Hm works for me .. can you just click on the NaN and change it to 0? ^^